# Dynamics AX 2009 :: Implications of Mutually Exclusive GLS Layers

Tags: architecture, internationalization, standards, axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

It’s my understanding that AX 2009 is constructed in such a way that Brazil, China and/or India cannot be on the same instance of AX as Russia and/or Poland as they have mutually exclusive GLS layers.  We’re nearing the stage where we will hit this conflict and so are looking into how to manage this.

Would anyone be able to point me to any documentation/blogs about this issue?  I’m hoping to find out more about the functional and technical implications and possible solutions.  I understand that AX 2012 does not have this issue, but would like to see what options we have in 2009 before making this decision.

Thanks in advance,

JB

If you want to know more about what I’m looking into, please see below:

- What are the functional impacts (so we can decide if the functionality introduced by the GLS layer is relevant to our requirements / can implement some countries without their GLS layer if our requirements aren't affected by this)?
- Is it possible to maintain one custom code base (i.e. in the VAR layer) for both instances, but using a different GLS layer in each?
- If the above is not simple, is it achievable by putting more code in the VAR layer to map the two GLS layer’s functionality to one common layer (i.e. so it behaves as if classes in both GLS layers implemented the same interface), perhaps then using the VAP layer for custom code and the USR layer for patches (since all code will be developed by our partner so we don't require this layer for our own purposes)?
- Is there any information on code management with multiple GLS layers?
- Is there a description of why this issue exists (from a technical point of view) so I can get a better idea of exactly what the cause of this issue is (i.e. what bit of the architecture causes a conflict for multiple countries / how come this couldn't be resolved by MS in AX 2009)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- What are the functional impacts (so we can decide if the functionality introduced by the GLS layer is relevant to our requirements / can implement some countries without their GLS layer if our requirements aren't affected by this)?

You're basically asking, "what's in the custom GLS layers for each country?"  I don't know this answer off hand, but one way to get an answer is in a clear environment, you can enable each GLS layer, create a layer compare project via (Tools> Development tools>Version Update>Compare layers) on the GLS layers, then export the GLS layer project only to an XPO and use WinDiff against the two XPOs.  This is all I can think of to quickly figure out differences.  It may be worth opening a ticket with Microsoft on this problem where the engineers working on the actual layers could provide you a better answer.

- Is it possible to maintain one custom code base (i.e. in the VAR layer) for both instances, but using a different GLS layer in each?

No.  If you had, for example, two AOS's, each with a different GLS layer, that communicated to the same database, it's basically two separate code bases.  Something could post differently depending on which environment it posts in.  This would be a bad path to go down.

- If the above is not simple, is it achievable by putting more code in the VAR layer to map the two GLS layer’s functionality to one common layer (i.e. so it behaves as if classes in both GLS layers implemented the same interface), perhaps then using the VAP layer for custom code and the USR layer for patches (since all code will be developed by our partner so we don't require this layer for our own purposes)?

**I'm thinking what you first need to do in this case** is determine exactly what the differences between the GLS layers are via code-compare.

The GLS layer which is pertinent to most of your business we will call **A**.  The other secondary GLS layer we will call **B**.

To do this, take your environment with GLS **B**, and do (Tools> Development tools>Version Update>Compare layers) and name your project GLS_B, choose your source GLS layer, then reference layer of sys, and click OK.  Once the private project is created, export the entire project to an XPO called GLS_B.xpo.

For this example, we will be working in the VAR layer, and I will assume your environment's layers are SYS, SYP, GLS, VAR, VAP, USR only.

Switch to your GLS **A** environment, remove **ALL layers** above GLS.  Open the import XPO tool (Ctrl+Shift+I from AOT), select the GLS_B.xpo, leave all defaults, then check "Show details", then the tedious work comes in, but click each object and do a compare.  If there are ANY differences, import the object.  If there are no differences, do not import.  Once you're done going over all objects, create another compare project of the VAR layer, and you will know your objects to look closely at.  Go through each of those items, see what the code differences are.

The fact that the GLS layers are separate for the different countries makes me think the differences could be significant or conflicting...so a simple merge might not resolve potential logic differences.  This is where you need to determine what to do next.  If the changes aren't that significant, you could merge into the VAR layer, make this your merged GLS layer that you leave alone, and do modifications in upper layers.

- Is there any information on code management with multiple GLS layers?

Not sure.  I'd think just my above method with TFS.

- Is there a description of why this issue exists (from a technical point of view) so I can get a better idea of exactly what the cause of this issue is (i.e. what bit of the architecture causes a conflict for multiple countries / how come this couldn't be resolved by MS in AX 2009)?

Not sure, it'd be worth contacting Microsoft for this issue.

Comment: That's great - thanks Alex. Good shout on using the layer compare tool; I recently became familiar with this, using a very similar process of exporting XPOs then windiffing to find the real differences.  The downside is, as you mention, this will be a lot of work just to do the comparison, then there's reverse engineering the code to figure out the functionality.  I'll try to find contact details for MS to see what they say before attempting the above.

Comment: With regards to the point about keeping the same code base, I'd be happy for the two instances to have completely different AOSes, Databases, even clients if needed.  The main thing is I'd prefer for our developers to be able to write code once and use it in (say) Poland and Brazil, rather than writing for both environments.  The way I'd envisioned was that they write this universal code in one layer, then maintain two copies of a lower layer which sits between the GLS and (say) VAR layer so that the VAR plugs into the same code, but this lower layer acts as an adapter for the GLS.

Comment: If you have two separate AOSs/DBs/Clients, then your companies are on two completely separate systems.  They won't be able to share customers/venders/General Ledger/etc.  I'd first determine the differences between the GLS layers and contact MS.  If it's significant, then the two separate environments may be the way to go.  There is no way to have one environment they develop on, and promote to both GLS environments, but that doesn't mean it is difficult to accomplish the same thing.  I'd be willing to bet that 75%+ of the development your developers do will not even touch GLS code.

Comment: They would just develop code in **GLS A** environment, check in TFS and get a version #.  Then they'd export their code and import it into the **GLS B** environment and merge/check it in and try to keep the same TFS version number.  They use the compare tool for differences.  They most likely have little, to no work required to merge the code in.  The GLS code I've seen is usually around country specific requirements, and most developers are programming general features that work across an entire company.

Comment: Thanks Alex; sounds like we'll likely need to go the second instance route then and look into writing some sort of TFS workflow piece to help ensure developers working on GLS A don't forget to copy their mod to GLS B (or vice versa).

Comment: That would be the easiest by far.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I have just installed the same two GLS layers in one AX 2009 instance. I have imported the second GLS layer into VAR/VAP and merged the differences in the CUS layer. It is quite a job to merge the layers, especially if your have a lot of customization and add-on modules installed.

MS recommends only to install one GLS layer per AX installation, and as you mention this will in your case require 2 live installations (there are 4 GLS layers for AX 2009).

I still think the best approach is to have both GLS layers in the same instance as it makes deployments easier and you will still be able to copy layers when deploying.

Comment: Great idea - thanks Steen.  Good to know that it's possible to do this / seems strange that MS didn't do it out of the box (or have you had to make compromises on what functionality to keep when merging / anything like that)?

Comment: MS had plans for one global GLS layer for AX 2009, however they never complete the job. I see the recommendation from MS to have one instance per GLS layer as a way to just pass on the problem. There is going to be one global GLS in 2012, I don't know whether it have been released yet for 2012.

Comment: I didn't have to do any compromises on the functionality. I have only increased the AOS buffer size from 24 to 30. Some of the methods which are about 300 lines in SYS/SYP layer ended up to be +1000 lines. I guess it is the cost of the multiple GLS layers. It would be better if the kernel could handle execution of country specific code, so GLS code could be put in country specific sub classes.